# Suspected memory leak with _beginthread

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, malloc, heap-memory, beginthread

So, i have some issues with i suspect a memory leak, in order to test i wrote this small code. By commenting the following line:

```
printf("Calc index: %d\n", ArrLength);
```

the code runs well. But when i uncomment it, the program crashed after a couple thousand threads.. When i use try/catch, the program just crashed inside the try function. Anyone who can help me out here?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <process.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    int StartNode;
    int EndNode;
    int GangID;
    int MemberID;
    int ArrLength;
    int arr[10000];
}t;
t *arg;
mutex m;

void myFunc(void *param) {
    m.lock();

    printf("Calculate thread started\n");
    t *args = (t*)param;
    int StartNode = args->StartNode;
    int EndNode = args->EndNode;
    int GangID = args->GangID;
    int MemberID = args->MemberID;
    int ArrLength = args->ArrLength;
    printf("Calc index: %d\n", ArrLength);

    free(args);

    m.unlock();
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        HANDLE handle;
        arg = (t *)malloc(sizeof(t));
        arg->StartNode = 2;
        arg->EndNode = 1;
        arg->GangID = 1;
        arg->MemberID = 1;
        arg->ArrLength = 5;
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
        {
            arg->arr[j] = j;
        }
        handle = (HANDLE)_beginthread(myFunc, 0, (void*)arg);
    }
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, let do some calc. Your `t` struct has 40020 bytes per instance. You do allocate it 1M times that causes about 40 Gb allocated in total. And this is not all the memory required because each thread is not for free. By default, Windows allocates 1Mb stack per thread that gives you 1 Tb (one terabyte) of memory required just to let the threads live.

So, total memory amount is something like 1040 Gb. Do you really intend that?

Comment: I free the struct everytime i create it, and as i mentioned, commenting the printf line makes the program run. The reserved memory only grows to big when the printf line is in place..

Comment: @JopHoeijmakers  `printf` is probably trying to obtain a lock to serialise output to the console. So the call to `free` never happens as threads are created faster than the console lock becomes available.

Comment: @JopHoeijmakers, you create them at once by the main thread, then trying to free under the mutex (e.g. sequentially, one thread per time). I'm pretty sure the resulting allocation is rocketing (because mutex means usermode-to-kernel call that is long one).

Comment: You guys are both right, by using printf the thread takes longer to execute and therefor the memory usage grows out of bounds as the create count runs up and they build down to slow.

Comment: Note that windows only reserves the virtual memory for the stack - its committed on demand. So the 1TB part of this is likely vastly overstating memory used.

Comment: @MikeVine, that's right. Same time, total amount of available virtual memory is kind of "page file size + RAM size" (rough formula). And if Topic-Starter doesn't have 1 Tb free space he can't even reserve that memory, thus "out of memory" crash.